# zsh truncates previous stdout when prompt width is same as COLUMNS

Tags: shell, printf, command-prompt, zsh

I have this simple zshrc which displays time in prommpt and resets it every 1 second
below is simplified version of my zshrc

```
repeat_string(){
  # this works fine
  printf "-%.0s" $(seq 1 $(( $COLUMNS - 1)))

  # this doesn't works fine
  # printf "-%.0s" $(seq 1 $COLUMNS)
}

TMOUT=1

TRAPALRM() {
  PROMPT="$(repeat_string)
  $(date)
  hello >>>"
  zle reset-prompt
}
```

I have simple function here `repeat_string` which I'm calling in my prompt string. purpose of this function is to display seperator (-) which has length equal to column width. It works fine when I pass repeat count which is not equal to $COLUMN. but if I pass $COLUMN, it behaves weird and truncates previous prompts and stdout also. Here is asciicinema link. https://asciinema.org/a/9FhIvtLD0XTnctEUXSRyZ9IrC

Use following script to quickly reproduce issue

```
mkdir /tmp/zshdebug
cat <<'EOF' > /tmp/zshdebug/.zshrc
repeat_string(){
  # this works fine
  printf "-%.0s" $(seq 1 $(( $COLUMNS - 1)))

  # this doesn't works fine
  # printf "-%.0s" $(seq 1 $COLUMNS)
}

TMOUT=1

TRAPALRM() {
  PROMPT="$(repeat_string)
  $(date)
  hello >>>"
  zle reset-prompt
}
EOF
ZDOTDIR=/tmp/zshdebug zsh
```

zsh version: zsh 5.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin16.0)

Answer (score 0):

Found solution here https://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2011/msg00052.html

> This is a problem with terminals and terminfo or termcap descriptions.
>   Some terminals silently discard a newline when one is output at the
>   right margin, others don't, and still others discard it only when it
>   is output at the right margin of the very last line of the screen.
>   Some terminals cause the cursor to wrap onto the next line right
>   away when the right margin is reached, others leave the cursor on
>   top of the last character that was output until at least one more
>   character appears.
>
> Terminal description databases aren't very good at differentiating
>   these cases.  ZLE decides in this case that the terminal both wraps
>   the line and does not discard the newline, so it believes it needs
>   to move up one line before redrawing the prompt.  Your terminal
>   wraps at the margin but does discard the newline, so ZLE's internal
>   idea of what the screen looks like does not match reality.
>
> You can get around this by replacing $'\n' with $'%1(l.\n.)' which
>   means to emit the newline only if ZLE believes that at least one
>   character has been output since the last (implicit) newline.  If
>   the line is exactly $COLUMNS wide, ZLE will think that the terminal
>   has wrapped and that zero characters have been output since, so it
>   won't fool itself by emitting a newline that the terminal discards.
>
> On a different terminal, though, you might need to go back to $'\n'
>   unconditionally.